# Clarifications on だって and って contractions

Tags: grammar, particle-って

Inquiring about whether i'm interpreting the following correctly, and what だって/って is abbreviated from in these sentences

> 誰だって知られたくない過去ってあるし、俺だってそうだから

*Anyone has things in the past that they don’t want to be known, I am the same.*

誰だって = 誰でも?　= no matter who/anyone

過去ってある = 過去___? = speaking of 過去, it exists

俺だって  = 俺___? = I ... too

> それだけじゃない、ほかの星座の神話だって有名なものだったらロマンチックに語ることができる。

*Not only that, if it's other famous constellational legends , i'm also able to romantically recite them.*

神話だって有名なもの = 神話という(の)有名なもの？

> オレ、ミステリーとの遭遇なんて夢物語だって心のどこかで思ってたんだよ

*For things like mysterious encounters, deep down I thought it was just a dream*

夢物語だって = 夢物語だと？= used just as a quote for 思って?

> ばいばいだって

*It’s saying bye-bye ( refering to a pet)*

ばいばいだって = ばいばいだといって？

> メアだって自分で自分の名前つけたんだろ

*Mare, you gave yourself a name didn't you?*

メアだって  = メア(というの)は? = = speaking of you, mare

But then what's the difference between using メアって and メアだって?

Compared to something like 新種のほ乳類**って**ほかに比べると格段にめずらしいらしい

*(speaking of) a new mammal species, compared to (discoveries of ) other kinds of new species, it's much more rare.*

Is the choice between って　and だって somewhat arbitrary in this usage?

Sorry for the long post, but i've been itching to get this ironed out for a while. Thank you.

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5336/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6-datte-meaning might help

Comment: Thanks, but i'm more looking for clarity in things other than the ...ても/even version. As listed in these sentences

Comment: Yeah, just something you could read while the full answer is here yet

Comment: Does this comment  help? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43239/why-can-だって-have-so-many-meanings#comment79946_43241

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 誰**だって**知られたくない過去**って**あるし、俺**だって**そうだから
>   誰だって = 誰でも?　= no matter who/anyone
>   過去ってある = 過去___? = speaking of 過去, it exists
>   俺だって = 俺___? = I ... too

Right.

誰だって means 誰でも. "No matter who" → "anyone".

The って in 過去って means は・というのは.
「知られたくない過去**は**ある」「知られたくない過去**というのは**ある」
*lit.* "Speaking of 知られたくない過去, it exists."

The だって in 俺だって means "also/too" or "even".

---

> それだけじゃない、ほかの星座の神話**だって**有名なものだったらロマンチックに語ることができる。
>
> 神話だって有名なもの = 神話という(の)有名なもの？

You're not parsing it correctly. ほかの星座の神話だって continues to ロマンチックに語ることができる, not 有名なもの.

ほかの星座の神話**だって**（有名なものだったら）（ロマンチックに）語ることができる。

The だって means "even" or "also".

Literally, "Adding to that, I can *also/even* （romantically） recite other constellational legends, （if they are famous）."

---

> オレ、『ミステリーとの遭遇なんて夢物語だ』**って**心のどこかで思ってたんだよ
>   For things like mysterious encounters, deep down I thought it was just a dream
>   夢物語だって = 夢物語だと？= used just as a quote for 思って?

Correct. The って is quotative. It's a colloquial variant of the quotative と.

---

> ばいばいだって

"(They said / I heard) Good bye."

Regarding this, you can refer to [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43241/9831).

---

> メア**だって**自分で自分の名前つけたんだろ
>   Mare, you gave yourself a name didn't you?
>
> メアだって = メア(というの)は? = = speaking of you, mare

No. The だって means "also."
"Mare *also* named herself, right?"
or "Mare, you *also* named yourself, right?" (speaking to Mare)

---

> Compared to something like 新種のほ乳類**って**ほかに比べると格段にめずらしいらしい
>
> (speaking of) a new mammal species, compared to (discoveries of) other kinds of new species, it's much more rare.

You're right. The って is a topical marker. It's a colloquial variant of 「は」「というのは」.

---

> Is the choice between って　and だって somewhat arbitrary in this usage?

I don't think it's arbitrary... You can't rephrase them as 「メア**って**自分で自分の名前つけたんだろ」「新種のほ乳類**だって**ほかに比べると格段にめずらしいらしい」

Comment: The other answer says 過去**って**ある＝過去**だって**ある but I disagree. 過去**って**ある means 過去**は・というのは**ある "Speaking of 過去, it exists -> There's 過去." and 過去**だって**ある means 過去**も**ある "過去 even/also exists."

Comment: i see thank you, just confirming, is 「は」/「というのは」 on applicable for って　and not a valid interpretation だって？

Comment: @charu Yeah... I think って can mean quotative と / topical は・というのは but I can't think of a situation where だって can be rephrased as は・というのは.

Comment: One more case if you don't mind, "だから明日歩にだって誤解される。" / "thus, (she is) misunderstood by Asuho

Comment: So (that's why) (she's) misunderstood by (also/even) Asuho. The だって is like も. 「だから明日歩に**も**誤解される。」

Answer (score 2):

だって and って are *colloquial* expressions.

> **だって 1**
>   [係助詞]  （断定の「だ」＋とて）
>   「でも」に似るが、語調がより強い。「鯨だって人間の仲間だ」
>   〔[デジタル大辞泉 | だって | **2**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137401/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/)〕

- 誰**だって**知られたくない過去**って**あるし、俺**だって**そうだから

誰だって＝誰でも、誰にも
過去ってある＝過去だってある＝過去もある
俺だって＝俺でも、俺にも、俺も

- ［ほかの星座の神話**だって**{有名なものだったら}］{ロマンチックに}語ることができる。

ほかの神話だって語ることができる＝ほかの神話(で)も語れる

- メア**だって**自分で自分の名前つけたんだろ  〔＝メアも〕

It seems

**だって＝でも** , **も**, or **にも**
**って≒は**：　メアって天才。／メアって天才？！／メアって天才！！
知られたくない過去**って**あるし＝知られたくない過去**は**あるものだし

---

> **だって 2**
>   [終助詞] 
>   引用句に付く。「欲しいくせに、いらないだってさ」
>   〔[デジタル大辞泉 | だって | **3**](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/137401/meaning/m1u/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/)〕

★Often the verb is the one that requires a certain particle:
**と思う, と言う, という**　＝って思う, って言う, っていう.

- オレ、［ミステリーとの遭遇なんて夢物語**だ**］**って**{心のどこかで}**思ってた**んだよ

＝夢物語だと思っていた

- ばいばい**だって**

(likely) = ばいばいだと（誰かが言った／誰かに言われた）。

Comment: ちょ・・「～～なんて夢物語**だって**心のどこかで思ってたんだよ」の「だって」を「終助詞」て・・・・

Comment: ah, this was a very nice consolidation thanks