# Is the use of "だって” regional or is it used everywhere?

Tags: expressions, dialects

I recently came across "datte" for example: "だって眠くないんだもの" Is this specific to a dialect
or used all over Japan?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5358/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/43241/9831

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can だって have so many meanings?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/43239/why-can-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a3%e3%81%a6-have-so-many-meanings)

Answer (score 1):

This [だって](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6/) is a word recognized by dictionaries. It is a part of the Standard Japanese vocabulary and safely understood in casual conversation without showing peculiar color, if not everyone from every region uses it spontaneously.