Trouble with だって before a comma

「……それでさ、ふりむいた男の口からは、真っ赤な血があふれていたんだ。どろどろ、だらだら。男はにまりと笑って、今度はおまえの番だって、女の子に手をのばしてきたんだ。...」

The above is the beginning of a chapter of a Japanese children's book. Now I am not sure if the character is reading a book or telling a story. Anyhow, I am unsure about the meaning of だって here. If I were to guess from https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5358/39455, I would say it means "because" but the problem here is that it's placed before a comma, not after it, which confuses me. Is this just an unorthodox placement of a comma?

In this case, it's the copula だ followed by the particle って which is used for quoting here, like と. 「今度はおまえの番だ」 is what he said ("Now/next it's your turn"). You might expect a verb like 言う. Instead the sentence just describes what he does: 女の子に手をのばしてきた.

Ohhhh, so instead of "Now it's your turn, he said" we have "Now it's your turn, (after saying this) he reached out for the girl"?

yes, that's right
